# Update model parameter with new data, discarding old data

Tags: python, scipy, machine-learning, numpy, regression

I have [this](https://pastebin.com/A3s9dUKp) dataset, and I am using `y = (a * x^n) / (b + x^n)` Hill function as the model, where `a` is the limit of the Hill curve, `b` is the point at which `a/2` is reached (for `n` = 1) and `n` is the cooperativity or steepness of the curve.

Currently, I am storing all `X,y` values, computing the parameters from `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`, and plotting the curve. If new data points come along, I re-calculate the parameters with the old+new data.

Is there a way to update the parameters of the model without storing **all** of the previous old data points, once the initial parameters are obtained from the previous data points?

Example, I fit the curve to the first 1000 data points and have my parameters. Next, I discard some or all of the old data. Then, when I see the 1001st point I simply update my parameters and plot the curve again and so on for every new data point.

**EDIT**

My existing code is as follows (not super elegant).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def file_stream(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as in_file:
        for line in in_file:
            yield map(float, line.strip().split('\t'))

def hill_model(X, a, b, n):
    return [float((a * x**n)) / (b + x**n) for x in X]

def get_params(X_all, y_all, prev_par=None, fn=hill_model):
    if prev_par is None:
        a_init, b_init, n_init = y_all[-1], y_all[0], 1.0
    else:
        a_init, b_init, n_init = prev_par
    opt_par, opt_cov = curve_fit(fn, X_all, y_all, p0=[a_init, b_init, n_init])
    a_final, b_final, n_final = opt_par
    return a_final, b_final, n_final

def main():
    file_name     = 'data.tsv'
    file_streamer = file_stream(file_name)
    X_all, y_all  = [], []

    # Get some intial data from stream
    for _ in xrange(1000):
        X, y = file_streamer.next()
        X_all.append(X)
        y_all.append(y)
    plt.scatter(X_all, y_all)

    # Initialize params of model
    a, b, n = get_params(X_all, y_all)
    y_model = hill_model(X_all, a, b, n)
    plt.plot(X_all, y_model, 'r-')
    plt.show()

    # Rolling update
    seen_all = False # Helps stop when all data is fit
    while True:
        for _ in xrange(1000):
            try:
                X, y = file_streamer.next()
                X_all.append(X)
                y_all.append(y)
            except:
                seen_all = True
                break
        a, b, n = get_params(X_all, y_all, prev_par=[a, b, n], fn=hill_model)
        y_model = hill_model(X_all, a, b, n)
        plt.scatter(X_all, y_all)
        plt.plot(X_all, y_model, 'r-')
        plt.show()

        # Nothing more to update, return
        if seen_all:
            return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The code currently reads in some `X,y` values, calculates the `a`, `b`, `n` parameters and when more `X,y` values are added, the code updates `a`, `b`, and `n` params. As you can see, I need to store previous `X,y` values, which I do not **want**. I want to update the parameters as new `X,y` values are seen and from the previous `a`, `b`, and `n` values only.

Comment: From your description, this seems like just a rolling window regression. A simple way to manage a constant $N$ number of pieces of data as you get new data is to create a queue data structure that pops oldest data out and pushes newest data in. One simple way to do this, if you know you'll have a constant $N$ pieces of data at all times, is to use an array as the queue and just move an index representing the location of the newest element in the array queue. Then you can just use the data in the queue to train your model.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @C. Howard, but I am not looking for regression over last N data points. I am looking to incrementally update my model paramters with new data. Retraining on the last N points will erase what I have learnt before that. More in the vein of on-line linear regression is what I seek, except my regression is non-linear.